# checkout steps are not working

Tags: checkout

suddenly our checkout is stopped working, i can not able to click on any of 5 steps. i am seeing 5 steps as below image how to debug & fix the issue? no steps are clickable. even i reverted to default theme, still same problem.

if i click on any steps in checkout , nothing is happening.

i disabled all the modules , but still its not working.

```
2016-04-06T19:25:21+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '')
#3 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', '')
#4 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(211): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
#10 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/company/public_html/3/em0113-full-package/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you start compilation????

Comment: @AsishHira no, how to do that ?

Comment: Login to backend . Then go system->tools->compilation. Then start compilation.

Comment: i got this at the time of compiling : http://prntscr.com/ap5jsc

Comment: @AsishHira its done now..... still same problem.....

Comment: i clearly show the some module you are remove still using in phtml file. check your phtml file check for third party block is calling.

Comment: @QaisarSatti can you please help me how to find in which phtml file its calling ? site [link](http://hotwheelstoys.in/3/em0113-full-package/index.php/)

Comment: check is console that will show which file is generate the error.

Comment: @QaisarSatti it don't show any phtml file , this is only error showing : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: `#checkout-step-billing {
    display: block !important;
}` add this to your css

Comment: @AsishHira nice, its working , but need one small change, please click [here](http://hotwheelstoys.in/3/em0113-full-package/index.php/customer/account/login/)

login with `email : kidsdial17@gmail.com & pw : totaltoys99` and than you can see "Billing information, once you click on

"continue" button, its moving to next step "shipping information" , its fine. but still Billing information section is displaying, but it should hide once we got to 2nd step.

Comment: OK remove that css code. And go to system->configuration. under **sales** you can see checkout. click on this and enable guest checkout->yes. then save.

Comment: @AsishHira now also "yes" is there.

Comment: You enabled guest checkout??

Comment: @AsishHira yes, it was enable before only.

Comment: I don't think so. caz still there is no option to checkout for guest

Comment: @AsishHira http://prntscr.com/ap7hdc i have no idea, wahts wrong, but it is "YES" now :

Comment: Do you checked my answer??? Do that thing ! change your store and then make it yes! do this for all stores

Comment: @AsishHira sorry, i did that , but no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that magento guest checkout is not enable. Try to enable guest check checkout By going to **System->configuration->sales->checkout** .

If you are using different stores then change store and enable for stores. Flush your cache.

There you go. Now you can see that checkout is working for logged in customer as well as not logged in customer